# How can I check value in dropdown for register form

Tags: list, flutter, validation, drop-down-menu

I have a registration form in my application and I want to check if the DropDown value is empty or not. So I will give a warning to the screen. But I couldn't use DropDown value on checkFieldStatus function. How can I get this?

These are my codes that i used for my app:

```
class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}
class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  List listGender = ["Erkek", "Kız"];
  List listTeacher = ["Oğulcan Baybars", "Kübra Yeşilkazak"];
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String genderHolder;
  String teacherHolder;
  var _imageFile = null;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomDropDownField(
              list: listGender,
              hintText: "Cinsiyet",
              value: genderHolder,
            ),
            CustomDropDownField(
              list: listTeacher,
              hintText: "Öğretmeniniz",
              value: teacherHolder,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  checkFieldStatus();
                },
                child: Text("Kayıt Ol")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> checkFieldStatus() async {
    if (_imageFile != null) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return ErrorAlertDialog(
              message: "Resim yüklendi",
            );
          });
    } else { 
    **Where I want to do the checks**
              ? registerUser()
              : displayDialog("Lütfen formdaki bütün alanları doldurun.";
    }
  }
}
```

My CustomDropDownField like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomDropDownField extends StatefulWidget {
  final List list;
  final String hintText;
  String value;

  CustomDropDownField({
    Key key,
    this.list,
    this.hintText,
    this.value,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomDropDownFieldState createState() => _CustomDropDownFieldState();
}
class _CustomDropDownFieldState extends State<CustomDropDownField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: DropdownButton(
          isExpanded: true,
          hint: Text(widget.hintText),
          items: widget.list.map((valueItem) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(value: valueItem, child: Text(valueItem));
          }).toList(),
          value: widget.value,
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              widget.value = newValue;
            });}),);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomDropDownField only changes the String value in its own state it does not reflect to the _RegisterState screen you can do a few different things:

1. Pass a callback function that updates the value in the _RegisterState screen

or even better

2. Use a state management like Provider or Bloc to update the value.